# Error while setting up lwc local development

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-local-development

Getting error while setting up salesforce lwc local development:

> PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\SajjanTestProject> sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
> Polling for new version(s) to become available on npm... done
> Successfully validated digital signature for @salesforce/lwc-dev-server.
> Finished digital signature check.
> Installing plugin @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest... failed
> »   Warning: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @salesforce/command@3.1.3: Package no longer supported. Contact
> »   Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
> Error: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\sf\client\2.30.8-d9ea14b\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js add
> @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\sf\yarn.lock
> --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\sf\yarn --check-files exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue and

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

fixed it for me. Apparantly this doesn't work for everyone. For a similar problem see [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/163).

Why [this is undocumented](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/set-up-lwc-local-dev) or unnecessary for some (such dependencies should be installed automatically), is beyond my knowledge.